# css repainted? then do something

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have an element that I would like to move animated or not animated using css, so if I have

html:

```
<div id="animate-me-maybe">content</div>
```

css:

```
#animate-me-maybe{
   position: absolute;
   left: 30%;
}

#animate-me-maybe.transition{
   transition: left 2s;
}

#animate-me-maybe.right{
   left: 80%;
}

#animate-me-maybe.no-animate{
   transition: none;
}
```

I want to be able to say `$('#animate-me-maybe').addClass('right')` and have it slowly move the right.
then
I want to be able to say `$('#animate-me-maybe').addClass('no-animate').removeClass('right')` and have it zip back to the left without an animation.

so...
      $('#animate-me-maybe').addClass('transition right').removeClass('transition right')

would have the div animate to the right, then blink back to the left.
I'm pretty sure the css renderer won't do anything because it waits for new things to happen.  so before it has a chance to render the animated portion, it notices that the div has moved back to its original place and therefore doesn't think it needs to bother

is there a way to do this without timeouts?  I've thought about adding a new element to the dom and setting a loop to make sure it's there before I proceed, but that seems very kludgy.

a better suggestion would be super helpful
thank you

Comment: use toggleClass()  may be it works

Comment: Include [Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) then you can just add and remove classes via jquery.

Comment: neato!  but of couse, I'm going to ask if there is a way to do it without adding a library.  :)

Comment: actually, this does give the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to SOIA.

CSS3 has animation Events.  so I can listen for an animationend event

```
$('#animate-me-maybe').addClass('transition
   right').one('animationend', function(){
      $('#animate-me-maybe').removeClass('transition right');
})
```

Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), where the ID rule takes precedence over the class rule

```js
$('#right').click(function() {
  $('#animate-me-maybe').removeClass('no-animate').addClass('right');
});
$('#left').click(function() {
  $('#animate-me-maybe').addClass('no-animate').removeClass('right')
});
```

```css
.parent {
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
#animate-me-maybe {
  transition: left 2s;
  position: absolute;
  left: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
#animate-me-maybe.right {
  left: 80%;
}
#animate-me-maybe.no-animate {
  transition: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="right">R</button>
<button id="left">L</button>
<div class="parent">
  <div id="animate-me-maybe">content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, good catch, but not quite what I was going for.  editing now